# C# .NET Web API CORS-Errors

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I've tried for days now and I can't get it to work.
I have a local web app and a local, separately running .NET 6.0 WebAPI which is supposed to accept post requests.

The web app which sends the fetch requests runs on localhost:3000
and the WebAPI runs on localhost:44379

My CORS-Policy is setup in the Program.cs file as follows:

appsettings.json:

```
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "cors": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "origin": "*",
        "allow": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin",
                    builder => builder
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()

                );
});
```

And then I use them before running the app, I also made sure to call the cors policy after the routing calls and before the Authorization calls:

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowMyOrigin");
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[image: Post Error]

I still get the cors error, also with enabled browser addons which should disable the issues on the browser.

I can't seem to figure out what is missing and would appreciate help

Comment: Your connection is completing since you got a response.  An error 400 usually means The server doesn't like either a header or the body.  I'm not sure if the COOR policy is returning the 400 or the real server is returning the 400.  Some servers send false error to confuse hackers when a request is not in the correct format.

Comment: Thank you for that hint, that is quite interesting! I already made sure the headers are correct when it comes to the content type etc.
So I will re-examine my body structure and debug it with some try/catch in the web api 

I have completely focused on the cors problem so far, but hopefully as you say it might not be the issue. I will report back once I did some testing.

Thanks jdweng!

Comment: If the web api is getting the request then it is not a COOR policy issue.  I didn't know that you had capability of debugging the server.

Comment: Alright I solved the issue. The problem was that a DateTime String of one of the attributes was not formatted correctly and therefore my JSON-payload got rejected. As for CORS everything was functioning properly already.

I will create an answer post to close the issue. Your tip helped me switch focus and so I found the problem. Thanks a lot! Now I can finish up my project :)

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out my CORS-Configurations were already properly set up.

As jdweng noted in the comments, the 400 response with the type: "cors" might have just been a false error in order to confuse hackers as some servers may do that.

This meant I switched focus on checking back on my Request-Headers and Payload and was able to identify an issue with the DateTime conversion of one of the Attributes of the JSON-Payload.

After fixing this, the requests came through and I also didn't get any CORS-Errors.

So in case you run into a similar issue and are already very sure about the proper setup for the CORS-options, be sure to debug your Fetch/Axios Request and implement proper error handling on the backend to see if the input model is valid and catch the errors to send back more detailed errors.

Comment: Not everybody as the luxury of being able to debug the server.